# How to automatically insert username into text box of login page & when logged in redirect to country/state/city stored in database using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The process is for the User to fill in his/her username & password then redirected to personinfo page and the username is now automatically inserted into that page, but when that page is complete the User is redirected to the login page and I want the username automatically inserted into the username text box. This is the code that exists;

```
<input type="text" name="user-name" style="width: 18%; height: 4mm"; />
```

And this is what I've tried but it doesn't work;

```
<input type="text" name="user-name" readonly value="<?php echo $username->user_name; ?>" style="width: 18%; height: 4mm"; />
```

Does the database need to be loaded into the Login Controller?

Then when the User is logged in I want to be redirected to the home page of the User's country/stateprovince/city that is stored in the database. I don't know where to start for that.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Send $username to the page where the user is giving another detail.

Comment: What you should do is in your login controller, do some logic so the password and username are validated, and then retrieve the logged in user, examine their country/city/state and have some logic which loads the relevant view file. When loading the view file, send along the username as data with it or anything else you need from the user object for the next view.

Comment: @user225359: So, (1) validate login (does username exist? pass correct?), if so -> (2) retrieve user object based on username/email -> (3) examine country/city/state of origin -> (4) load appropriate view file based on this, sending along username with it (as an associated array)